# clearInterval does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a simple countdown timer. It counts down from the number entered.

However, I'm trying to clear the interval when the counter gets to `0`. At the moment it seems to acknowledge the `if statement`, but not `clearInterval()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/cf3Hd/

```
$('.click').click(function () {
    $('input').empty();
    var rawAmount = $('input').val();
    var cleanAmount = parseInt(rawAmount) + 1;

    var timer = function () {

        cleanAmount--;

        if (cleanAmount == 0) {

            clearInterval(timer);
        }
        $('p').text(cleanAmount);
    };

    setInterval(timer, 500);

})
```

Comment: It works fine when you use it correctly. You don't pass a function to `clearInterval()`. You pass the return value from `setInterval()`. [MDN `clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval) Always a good idea to consult documentation to learn how a function works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not saving the return value of the call to `setInterval`, which is the value that needs to be passed to `clearInterval`. Passing the timer handler does no good.

```
var timer, timerHandler = function () {

    cleanAmount--;

    if (cleanAmount == 0) {

        clearInterval(timer);
    }
    $('p').text(cleanAmount);
};

timer = setInterval(timerHandler, 500);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. However I'm not quite sure why?

Comment: @tmyie The `setInterval()` function returns a value. The value is just a number, but it serves to identify that particular timer you started among others that might be running. It's that "key" that you have to use when you want to tell the browser to stop running the timer.

Comment: Thanks. Would you know why .empty() does not appear to be working? http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/cf3Hd/2/

Comment: @tmyie the `.empty()` function is for clearing out the contents of container elements, but `<input>` elements are not containers and will never have any contents. If you want to clear the **value** of the input, use `$('input').val("")` (which clears every input on the page)